# I have created a webpage in which footer div not working

Tags: html, css

I am html/css beginner and Created this webpage in which there is three main divs header,boxcontainer,footer.

there is some problem with footer div that its background is not showing before its text. i have used float in box container divs.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        div#header {
            margin-left: 1%;
            background-color: lightblue;
            height: 30px;
            width: 95%;
        }

        ul#menu li {
            margin: 10px;
            color: black;
            font-size: 25px;
            display: inline;
            margin-top: 100px;
        }

            ul#menu li:hover {
                color: white;
            }

        div.box {
            background-color: lightblue;
            height: 200px;
            width: 200px;
            float: left;
            margin: 10px;
            width: 30.3%;
        }

        div.boxhead {
            background-color: yellow;
            height: 30px;
            padding: 0px;
            width: 100%;
        }

            div.boxhead p {
                font-size: 150%;
                text-align: center;
                color: lightblue;
                height: 30px;
                width: 200px;
                padding: 0px;
                -webkit-margin-before: 0.0em;
                -webkit-margin-after: 0.0em;
            }

        div#footer {
            margin-left: 1%;
            background-color: lightblue;
            height: 30px;
            width: 95%;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div style="margin: auto;width: 95%;" id="container">
        <div></div>
        <div id="header">
            <ul id="menu">
                <li>Home</li>
                <li>Events</li>
                <li>About</li>
                <li>Contect us</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="boxcontainer">

            <div class="box">
                <div class="boxhead">
                    <p>Events<p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="box">
                <div class="boxhead">
                    <p>Become a Sponser</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="box">
                <div class="boxhead">
                    <p>Gallery</p>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div id="footer">
            <p style="text-align:center">Copyright © 2015  All rights reserved | Privacy Policy | Terms and Conditions | Email: @gmail.com</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clear the float for the footer using `clear:both`

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    div#header {
      margin-left: 1%;
      background-color: lightblue;
      height: 30px;
      width: 95%;
    }
    ul#menu li {
      margin: 10px;
      color: black;
      font-size: 25px;
      display: inline;
      margin-top: 100px;
    }
    ul#menu li:hover {
      color: white
    }
    div.box {
      background-color: lightblue;
      height: 200px;
      width: 200px;
      float: left;
      margin: 10px;
      width: 30.3%;
    }
    div.boxhead {
      background-color: yellow;
      height: 30px;
      padding: 0px;
      width: 100%;
    }
    div.boxhead p {
      font-size: 150%;
      text-align: center;
      color: lightblue;
      height: 30px;
      width: 200px;
      padding: 0px;
      -webkit-margin-before: 0.0em;
      -webkit-margin-after: 0.0em;
    }
    div#footer {
      clear: both;
      margin-left: 1%;
      background-color: lightblue;
      height: 30px;
      width: 95%;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div style="margin: auto;width: 95%;" id="container">
    <div></div>
    <div id="header">
      <ul id="menu">
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>Events</li>
        <li>About</li>
        <li>Contect us</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="boxcontainer">

      <div class="box">
        <div class="boxhead">
          <p>Events
            <p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="box">
        <div class="boxhead">
          <p>Become a Sponser</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="box">
        <div class="boxhead">
          <p>Gallery</p>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div id="footer">
      <p style="text-align:center">Copyright © 2015 All rights reserved | Privacy Policy | Terms and Conditions | Email: @gmail.com</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: tnks that solved my problem but  i have set float only for BOX class so why it is affecting on other divs

Answer (score 1):

hi you can add this code for footer : `clear:both`

```
 div#footer {
    margin-left: 1%;
    background-color: lightblue;
    height: 30px;
    width: 95%;
    clear: both;
}
```

and for more reference see this link : https://jsfiddle.net/

thanks

Answer (score 1):

> Always set layout of parent element while using `float` on child
>   elements.

You haven't set layout of parent element in your code.
There are many ways of setting layout. You can use `overflow: hidden` i.e:

```
#boxcontainer {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Alternatively you can use `:after` pseudo element as well:

```
#boxcontainer:after {
  display: block;
  content: '';
  clear: both;
}
```

```css
div#header {margin-left:1%;background-color:lightblue;height:30px;width:95%;}
ul#menu li {margin:10px;color:black;font-size:25px;display:inline;margin-top:100px;}
ul#menu li:hover{color:white}
div.box { background-color:lightblue;height:200px;width:200px;float:left;margin:10px;width:35%;}
div.boxhead {background-color:yellow;height:30px;padding:0px;width:100%;}
div.boxhead p {font-size:150%;text-align:center;color:lightblue;height:30px;width:200px;padding:0px;-webkit-margin-before: 0.0em;-webkit-margin-after:0.0em;}
div#footer {margin-left:1%;background-color:lightblue;width:95%;}

#boxcontainer {overflow: hidden;}
```

```html
<div style="margin: auto;width: 95%;"id="container">
  <div></div>
  <div id="header">
    <ul id="menu">
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>Events</li>
      <li>About</li>
      <li>Contect us</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="boxcontainer">

    <div class="box">
      <div class="boxhead">
        <p>Events<p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="box">
      <div class="boxhead">
        <p>Become a Sponser</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="box">
      <div class="boxhead">
        <p>Gallery</p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div id="footer">
    <p style="text-align:center">Copyright © 2015  All rights reserved | Privacy Policy | Terms and Conditions | Email: @gmail.com</p>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a `<div>`, try using the tag `<footer>`.

**html**

```
<footer class="footer">
    <p>Your content</p>
</footer>
```

**css**

```
.footer{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 1rem;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are two solutions for your case:

1. Remove the float of the *footer* div

   ```
   #footer {
        float:none;
   }
   ```

or

2.Add helper class `clearfix` to your *footer* div:

```
<div id="footer" class="clearfix">
```

with the following style, which will clear the float

```
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
    content: " "; /* 1 */
    display: table; /* 2 */
}

.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `.clearfix` class to the parent of float elements:

```
<div id="boxcontainer" class="clearfix">...</div>
```

CSS for `.clearfix`:

```
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
   content: " ";
   display: table;
}

.clearfix:after {
   clear: both;
}
```

Also, I think that you need not fixed height at your footer. So, remove `height: 30px;` from your footer div.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        div#header {
            margin-left: 1%;
            background-color: lightblue;
            height: 30px;
            width: 95%;
        }

        ul#menu li {
            margin: 10px;
            color: black;
            font-size: 25px;
            display: inline;
            margin-top: 100px;
        }

            ul#menu li:hover {
                color: white;
            }

        div.box {
            background-color: lightblue;
            height: 200px;
            width: 200px;
            float: left;
            margin: 10px;
            width: 30.3%;
        }

        div.boxhead {
            background-color: yellow;
            height: 30px;
            padding: 0px;
            width: 100%;
        }

            div.boxhead p {
                font-size: 150%;
                text-align: center;
                color: lightblue;
                height: 30px;
                width: 200px;
                padding: 0px;
                -webkit-margin-before: 0.0em;
                -webkit-margin-after: 0.0em;
            }

        .clearfix:before,
        .clearfix:after {
            content: " ";
            display: table;
         }

         .clearfix:after {
             clear: both;
         }

        div#footer {
            margin-left: 1%;
            background-color: lightblue;
            width: 95%;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div style="margin: auto;width: 95%;" id="container">
        <div></div>
        <div id="header">
            <ul id="menu">
                <li>Home</li>
                <li>Events</li>
                <li>About</li>
                <li>Contect us</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="boxcontainer" class="clearfix">

            <div class="box">
                <div class="boxhead">
                    <p>Events<p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="box">
                <div class="boxhead">
                    <p>Become a Sponser</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="box">
                <div class="boxhead">
                    <p>Gallery</p>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div id="footer">
            <p style="text-align:center">Copyright © 2015  All rights reserved | Privacy Policy | Terms and Conditions | Email: @gmail.com</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `height: 30px` from footer and add `float: left`;

```
div#footer {
    margin-left: 1%;
    background-color: lightblue;
    width: 95%;
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First You need to set the style for footer

```
#footer {
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
width:100%;
height:60px;   /* Height of the footer */
background:#6cf;
}
```

Then You call

```
<div id="footer">footer</div>
```